# Node socket hang up on twitter stream filter.json get

Tags: node.js, httpwebrequest

I have the following simple Coffeescript code to access the Twitter [Stream API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter)

```
http = require 'http'

options =
    port: 443
    host: 'stream.twitter.com'
    path: '/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=keyword'
    headers:
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer('[user]:[pass]').toString 'base64'
        'Host': 'stream.twitter.com'
    method: 'GET'

callback = (res) ->
    console.log res
    res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
        console.log chunk

    res.on 'end', -> console.log 'end'

    # res.on 'close', -> res.emit 'end'

http.request options, callback
```

Why am I getting

```
throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: socket hang up
```

Answer (score 2):

An error is triggering the `error` event on your response (`res`), which you are not listening for. By default, `error` events in Node.js EventEmitters, if not listened for, will throw. You need to add

```coffeescript
res.on 'error', # whatever
```

and handle the error.

Note that this will just keep the error from being thrown; it won't stop the error from occurring.

Comment: When you say 'handle the error', do you mean merely catching it is enough, e.g. something like "res.on 'error', (err) -> null"? Cause I have tried it and still get the same 'socket hang up'. Much appreciated!

Comment: Well, if the socket is hanging up, you'll definitely have to deal with it (reconnect, etc), but having a function should at least make it stop throwing.